# Unable to import WordPress header outside of WP

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I want to use the WordPress header to the outside of WP so that the header part remain same.

My WP URL: abc.com/in

My PHP Custom Application: abc.com/portal

Now, I want to use the WP header to my custom developed PHP application.

I am using this code on my custom PHP application to import the WP header.

```
<?
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('/home/abc/public_html/in/wp-load.php');
get_header(); 
?>
```

I am getting the header but not properly formatted, mostly CSS is missing.

Using `Elementor Builder` and  `Header Footer Elementor` plugin.

Please help to fetch the header.

Comment: Try to add the `wp_footer();` too because all the scripts and styles that load in this hook.

Comment: No, its same   :(